# Android won't recognize multiple buttons at the same time

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

The app I am currently working on has 2 players, each with 2 buttons.  When the app is built in Android Studio, if one button is being held down it still accepts presses from the other 3.  When I began using IntelliJ IDEA 10, while one button is being held down all other buttons are locked down.  All the code for both is the same, so is this a result of the Gradle build?  What should I be doing to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that below android API 11 it does not programmatically support multi-touch while the device physically does support it.  I solved this by setting the min SDK to 10 while setting the target SDK to 11.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on if your mobile device accepts multi-touch or not.

Comment: the apps are being executed on the exact same phone